# Why does an http get method accepts http post request in asp.net web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

I have an `HTTP-GET` method looks like below one

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CityController : ControllerBase
{
    public ActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var city = new { CityName = "Gotham" };
            return Ok(city);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500);
        }
    }
}
```

For both type of the requests

Request:

```
GET http://localhost:49915/api/city
POST http://localhost:49915/api/city
```

Response:

```
status: 200 OK
-------------------
{
    "cityName": "Gotham"
}
```

Now my questions around it are,

1. As it is a `GET`, should it supposed to accept a `POST`?
2. Shouldn't it return a 405 status code and Why it does not? (at least I'm expecting)
3. In such case, if I have to return 405 what to be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As it is a GET, should it supposed to accept a POST?

While you assume it is a get because of the action name and convention-based routing, you would be mistaken as the controller has been decorated for attribute routing.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

and thus ignores convention based routes if a match is made. Note that `PUT` and `DELETE`

```
PUT http://localhost:49915/api/city
DELETE http://localhost:49915/api/city
```

should also work on the same action.

> Shouldn't it return a 405 status code and Why it does not? (at least I'm expecting)

The action matches both calls by design since no directive was given for the action.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CityController : ControllerBase {
    // GET api/city?id=2 //Note id would be optional as a query variable.
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get(int id) {
        try {
            var city = new { CityName = "Gotham" };
            return Ok(city);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            return StatusCode(500);
        }
    }
}
```

Now with the `HttpGet` in place, if

```
POST http://localhost:49915/api/city
```

or another HTTP method is done, you will get the 405 error because the path matches but the method does not.

> In such case, if I have to return 405 what to be done?

with the attribute route in place, the framework will do it for you so there is nothing more for you to do.

Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

> ### Mixed routing: Attribute routing vs conventional routing
>
> What distinguishes the two types of routing systems is the process applied after a URL matches a route template. In conventional routing, the route values from the match are used to choose the action and controller from a lookup table of all conventional routed actions. In attribute routing, each template is already associated with an action, and no further lookup is needed.

Comment: Appreciate your reply and now I'm getting the point. What I also have noticed is by adding `[HttpGet]` does prevent from making a `POST` call however it returns 404 which is fine but I'm no expert yet I think 405 is more appropriate. :)